# Trying to compile HDF5 on MinGW/MSYS

Tags: windows, build, mingw, patch, hdf5

I'm trying to patch HDF5 1.8.9 in order to compile it on MinGW with this patches I found from http://www.digipedia.pl/usenet/thread/15809/3624/

I tried with msys-patch

```
patch <patchfile.patch
```

Following one gave me

```
(Stripping trailing CRs from patch.)
patching file configure.in
patch: **** malformed patch at line 4: dnl rebuild rules.
```

---

```
**** Patch for configure.in
*******************************************
--- /tmp/hdf5-1.8.9/configure.in.old    2012-05-09 10:07:27.000000000 -0500
+++ /tmp/hdf5-1.8.9/configure.in    2012-07-18 16:51:35.000000000 -0500
@@ -49,6 +49,16 @@
dnl rebuild rules.
AM_MAINTAINER_MODE

+AC_ARG_WITH(mingw, [--with-mingw    enable compilation with gnu gcc under
mingw])
+AM_CONDITIONAL([WITH_MINGW], [test "$with_mingw" = "yes"])
+if test "$with_mingw" = "yes"; then
+  AC_DEFINE([HAVE_WINDOWS],[1],[Define if the Windows virtual file driver
should be compiled])
+  AC_DEFINE([HAVE_MINGW],[1],[Define if on mingw])
+  AC_DEFINE([HAVE_WIN32_API],[1],[Define if on the Windows platform])
+dnl We also need to add a -lwsock32 to avert _WSAStartup@8 errors
+  LIBS="$LIBS -lwsock32"
+fi
+
dnl Run post processing on files created by configure.
dnl src/H5pubconf.h:
dnl Generate src/H5pubconf.h from src/H5config.h by prepending H5_ to all
```

And the other one

```
(Stripping trailing CRs from patch.)
patching file Makefile.am
patch: **** malformed patch at line 7: H5Zdeflate.c H5Zfletcher32.c H5Znbit.c H5
Zshuffle.c H5Zszip.c  \
```

---

```
**** Patch for src/Makefile.am
*******************************************
--- /tmp/hdf5-1.8.9/src/Makefile.am.old    2012-05-09 10:05:58.000000000
-0500
+++ /tmp/hdf5-1.8.9/src/Makefile.am    2012-07-18 16:54:27.000000000 -0500
@@ -103,6 +103,9 @@
H5Zdeflate.c H5Zfletcher32.c H5Znbit.c H5Zshuffle.c H5Zszip.c  \
H5Zscaleoffset.c H5Ztrans.c

+if WITH_MINGW
+ libhdf5_la_SOURCES+=H5FDwindows.c
+endif

# Public headers
include_HEADERS = hdf5.h H5api_adpt.h H5overflow.h H5pubconf.h H5public.h
H5version.h \
@@ -115,6 +118,10 @@
H5MMpublic.h H5Opublic.h H5Ppublic.h H5Rpublic.h H5Spublic.h \
H5Tpublic.h H5Zpublic.h

+if WITH_MINGW
+ libhdf5_la_SOURCES+=H5FDwindows.h
+endif
+
# install libhdf5.settings in lib directory
settingsdir=$(libdir)
settings_DATA=libhdf5.settings
```

If anyone can tell me how to patch this correctly or another way around,I'll be thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a patch expert so I can't tell you where is the error in the patches but I can give you another solution: since the patches are so small, why don't you update the said files directly?

Just locate where the additions should go using the line numbers (between `@@`) and the few lines of context (lines without leading `+` or `-`) and add at the right locations the additional lines (those starting with a `+`, and of course don't forget to remove the leading `+` signs when you do).